# Creating more than one contextMenu on Selection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

Currently I am working on fixing up a Chrome Extension. My last problem is that I am trying to create two contextMenus when a person scrolls over something and right clicks.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "One: '%s'",
    contexts:["selection"],
    id:'sat'
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Two: '%s'",
    contexts:["selection"],
    id:'dat'
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){...
```

When I test it it only creates the first one.

Answer (score -1):

You can only create one parent with multiple child menus and not two parents in the main context. Whilst a child can be a parent as well.

Try this sample: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:context

Comment: How would I add a child?